# Slickgrid minWidth and maxWidth ignored

Tags: slickgrid

Slickgrid seems to be ignoring the [minWidth and maxWidth attributes](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/API-Reference).  Am I missing something?

Note in the following jsFiddle, one of the columns has a *width* of 300 which is honored, while the other columns have *minWidth* and *maxWidth* set to 300 without any effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/ericjohannsen/ZSJEj/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minWidth & maxWidth only apply to column resizing operations or when the columns are auto-sized.  You are still expected to specify the initial width.

UPDATED:  I've added column width clamping to SlickGrid.

Comment: Could you elaborate on exactly what *column width clamping* means?

Comment: minWidth & maxWidth are now enforced on the initial render and the column width, whether specified explicitly or inherited from defaults,  is forced to respect the bounds.